# If a serializer serializes a proxy proxilizes,proxifies,proxifieres?

Tags: single-word-requests

Trying to find a word for what a proxy does by it's own root.
Some words are easier e.g. serializer serializes etc.
some words are hard e.g. proxy (proxilizes,proxifies,proxifieres?) not sure what is making the two so different, anyone can shed light on the aspect that is at play here please

I am tagging this as a single word request, but I don't know what is the proper tag for finding the aspects I am looking for, any help on that too is apreciated

Comment: One is tempted to say "proselytizes", and, in fact, that's not too far off.  A proxy (the computer type) doesn't transform the data itself but acts as an intermediary between two other points in a network.

Comment: A proxy ***proxies***...  OR   proxies ***proxy*** - take your pick ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may sound lame, but a proxy... **acts as a proxy**. Cf. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proxy):

> Since I wouldn't be available to vote, I nominated him to act as my proxy.

Answer (score 1):

It's always hard to say why one coinage becomes part of the language while another parallel coinage fails to do so.  In the case of *proxy*, the *OED* records the verb "to proxy" as rare, but it has a technical usage in geology (dating from 1922) to mean the substitution of one mineral or rock type for another in a geological formation.  More recently, the term *proxify* has come to mean to route a computer connection through a server (called the proxy) to hide your identifying IP address and thus make your actions anonymous.  One of these services is called Proxify.com.

Answer (score 1):

In some contexts, proxy itself is acceptable as a verb; for example, in computing technology, when a proxy server is doing its thing, it is often referred to simply as "proxying;" phrases such as "this server will proxy the requests sent into it" are perfectly reasonable.